# Web Analytics Reset

Tags: web-analytics

Is it possible to reset the numbers reported in Web Analytics? We have created some sites and have tested them out but want to see what the actual usage is, excluding our testing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a new system and you can remove all analytics then the easiest way to do it will likely be to drop and re-provision the Web Analytics Service App which will re-provision new databases.

From what I understand the official stance is that the Web Analytics Reporting database is the one database that supports direct querying and potentially deletions.  With that said, the underlying schema is not well documented so I'm not sure what you would need to delete to reset the stats.

Answer (score 0):

If your testing traffic originates from the same user accounts, just exclude those user accounts from the web analytics reports.